# Question regarding strong and weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, weak-convergence

The definitions are for a normed linear space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$

> **Strong convergence**. It is said that $\{x_n\} \subseteq X$ converges strongly to some limit $x$ if,
> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|x_n - x\| = 0.$$

> **Weak convergence**. If for all linear functionals (bounded) $f \in X^*$ where $X^*$ denotes the dual space, the sequence $\{x_n\} \subseteq X$ converges weakly to some limit $x$ if
> $$f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$$

My question is then:

> the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to some limit $x$ if for **any** bounded linear functional $f$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges strongly to $f(x)$? That is
> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|f(x_n) - f(x)\|=0$$

Comment: Notice that $f(x_n),f(x)\in\mathbb R$, so $\|f(x_n)-f(x)\|$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Surb OP probably just means $|f(x_n) - f(x)|$.

Comment: Okey to see if I got this right; in case of $X$ the induced metric is $d(x,y)=||x-y||$ so basically in the definition of strong convergence, the distance should be infinitesimal (or just 0). As @Surb points out, $||\cdot||$ does not make any sense since it with respect to the "wrong" space (i.e. $X$ and not $\mathbb{R}$). As $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ is a metric on the reals, can one make the analogy that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f(x_n) - f(x)|$ is strongly converging in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Strong convergence is same as ordinary convergence in finite dimensional spaces, in particular in the real line.